# Electron - running into some issues with start command and window sizing

Tags: javascript, electron

So I've built a trivial application using Electron.

I can start the app using the command 'electron index.html, but not the command 'electron .', even though this is explicitly declared in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "remind-me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "information management tool",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "tokumk"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.11"
  }
}
```

a second issue related to window sizing. my BrowserWindow is always the same size regardless of setting it to something else. Here is an example of my index.js. The setting background color is also completely ignored.

index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h3>remind me</h3>
            <form>
                <input type = text action="post"></input>
                <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">
            <form>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        require('./renderer.js');
    </script>

</html>
```

index.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = ('url');

// window object
let win;

function createWindow(){

    // set window size and background color
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 450, 
        height: 400,
        backgroundColor: '#2e2c29'
    });

    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dir, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));


    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    win.on('closed', ()=> {
        win = null;
    });

    app.on('ready', createWindow);

    app.on('window-all-closed', ()=>{
        if(process.platform !== 'darwin'){
            app.quit();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: At the top you say: I can start the app using the command 'electron index.html, did you mean `electron index.js`? You should also split your question into two different questions

Comment: no i meant electon index.html. thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: when you say always the same size regardless of setting it to something else do you mean you can't resize it manually or you can't use `win.setSize()`?

Comment: hi mike if you look at the BrowserWindow constructor you can see the hardcoded values for width and height. These setting are not reflected in the browser window when running the application.

Comment: Can you please show your `index.html` file

Comment: added to orginal post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148401/discussion-between-mike-wood-and-jcire).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're running the application like `electron index.html` which just loads `index.html` in a window and nothing else so if you run electron like: `electron index.js` I think it would work